# Polymer - Show empty state on nested dom-repeat with filter

Tags: polymer, dom-repeat

I have a nested `dom-repeat` to first iterate employees in company and then iterate projects of the employee, also when iterating projects I'm using a filter to get only success projects.
Tried to use renderedItems but it's giving number of employees always. Instead i need a way to know the status when no employee have any succeeded projects. (simply when no items listed)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.6.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.6.0/lib/polymer/polymer.html" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <test-element></test-element>
  <dom-module id="test-element">
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>Test Element</h1>
        <h3>Rendered Count: [[renderedCount]]</h3>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{!renderedCount}}">
          <img src="https://emptyensemble.com/wp-content/themes/emptyensemble2015/assets/images/empty_ensemble_empty_set_logo.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:250px;height:250px;">
        </template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}" as="employee" rendered-item-count="{{renderedCount}}">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employee.projects}}" filter="{{_filterProjects()}}" as="employeeProject">
            <span>Test 1 [[employeeProject.name]]</span>
            <br>
          </template>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'test-element',
        properties: {
          employees: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [{
                name: 'user1',
                projects: [{
                  name: 'proj1',
                  status: false
                }, {
                  name: 'proj2',
                  status: true
                }, {
                  name: 'proj3',
                  status: true
                }]
              }, {
                name: 'user2',
                projects: [{
                  name: 'proj4',
                  status: false
                }, {
                  name: 'proj5',
                  status: false
                }]
              }]
            }
          },
          renderedCount: {
            type: Number
          }
        },

        _filterProjects: function() {
          return function(item) {
            return item.status;
          };
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So do you want to know number of employees with 0 success projects?

Comment: @a1626 Ah not actually, want to know the status where there are no any succeeded projects means the printed none. So then need to show an empty-state.

Comment: Still not clear can you explain with using ur plunkr as example? Which porjects/users from your plunkr you expect to be counted?

Comment: @a1626 Actually the state where no employees have success projects. No content. So no items like 'Test 1 proj2' are printed.

Comment: So are you saying a state where status of all the projects is false?

Comment: If so, then what do you want to know? Number of employees?

Comment: @a1626 Yeah the state when all projects false. But through dom-repeat itself. For example in single dom-repeat you can get it through renderedItemCount. Simply nothing added through dom-repeat, it's enough to have polymer property set to show or hide hide empty state image. Currently I'm using outer dom-repeat renderedItemsCount property which have value 2 all the time (number of employees) despite the employee have success projects (inner dom-repeat)

Comment: You are not using `renderItemCount` for what it's intended. It is going to tell how many items were rendered. As you first dom-repeat is rendering both the objects the count is 2

Comment: @a1626 Ah ok, so is there another way that I can get the empty state?

Comment: Instead of binding to `renderCount` you can bind it to a function where you can iterate and check the required. Your dom-repeat will not print anything anyways if every value is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried few ways to resolve this issue and identified two types on showing empty state. (Actually got the help from polymer slack channel and thought of sharing the information with some samples)

You can try by changing the employee array in following code samples, by setting projects status true or false to see the empty state changing.

1. Show empty state by employee - When any employee don't have success projects show an empty state

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.6.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.6.0/lib/polymer/polymer.html" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <test-element></test-element>
  <dom-module id="test-element">
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>Company Projects</h1>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}" as="employee" rendered-item-count="{{renderedCount}}">
          <br>
          <b><span>[[employee.name]]</span></b>
          <br>
          <div hidden$="{{_computeEmpty(employee.innercount)}}">
            <img src="https://emptyensemble.com/wp-content/themes/emptyensemble2015/assets/images/empty_ensemble_empty_set_logo.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:250px;height:250px;">
          </div>
          <br>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employee.projects}}" filter="{{_filterProjects()}}" as="employeeProject" rendered-item-count="{{employee.innercount}}">
            <span>Project: [[employeeProject.name]]</span>
            <br>

          </template>

        </template>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'test-element',
        properties: {
          employees: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [{
                name: 'user1',
                projects: [{
                  name: 'proj1',
                  status: true
                }, {
                  name: 'proj2',
                  status: false
                }, {
                  name: 'proj3',
                  status: false
                }]
              }, {
                name: 'user2',
                projects: [{
                  name: 'proj4',
                  status: false
                }, {
                  name: 'proj5',
                  status: false
                }]
              }]
            }
          },
          renderedCount: {
            type: Number
          },
          innercount: {
            type: Number
          }
        },
        _computeEmpty: function(projects) {
          return (projects > 0);
        },
        _filterProjects: function() {
          return function(item) {
            return item.status;
          };
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

2. Show empty state by company - When no employee have success projects show an empty state

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.6.0/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.6.0/lib/polymer/polymer.html" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <test-element></test-element>
  <dom-module id="test-element">
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>Company Projects</h1>
        <br>
        <b><span>Succeeded Projects</span></b>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div hidden$="{{!showEmptyState}}">
          <img src="https://emptyensemble.com/wp-content/themes/emptyensemble2015/assets/images/empty_ensemble_empty_set_logo.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:250px;height:250px;">
        </div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}" as="employee">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employee.projects}}" filter="{{_filterProjects()}}" as="employeeProject" rendered-item-count="{{renderedCount}}">
            <span>[[employee.name]]: [[employeeProject.name]]</span>
            <br>

          </template>

        </template>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'test-element',
        properties: {
          employees: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [{
                name: 'user1',
                projects: [{
                  name: 'proj1',
                  status: false
                }, {
                  name: 'proj2',
                  status: false
                }, {
                  name: 'proj3',
                  status: false
                }]
              }, {
                name: 'user2',
                projects: [{
                  name: 'proj4',
                  status: false
                }, {
                  name: 'proj5',
                  status: false
                }]
              }]
            }
          },
          renderedCount: {
            type: Number,
            observer: '_onInnerRenderedCountChanged'
          },
          showEmptyState: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: true
          }
        },
        _onInnerRenderedCountChanged: function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue > 0) {
            this.set('showEmptyState', false);
          }
        },
        _filterProjects: function() {
          return function(item) {
            return item.status;
          };
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```